# Laravel token confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, token

I have a basic question.

Laravel tokens works for password reset.

In my case, i'd like to use it for a change request sent by user (via custom change form) which is going to be accepted/refused by an admin. Can tokens be used that way ?

**View :**

```
<form action="{{ action('myController@changeResult') }}" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
   <input type="radio" name="accept" value="accept">
   <input type="label">Accept</label>
   <input type="radio" name="refuse" value="refuse">
   <input type="label">Refuse</label>
   <input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</form>
```

Then posting the value into myController controller's changeResult method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your question.  Since from what I see, you're using CSRF tokens which is unique to each user and form request.  So long as your route has the `CheckCsrfToken` or whatever it is, it'll always pass.  So what are you trying to achieve/what is the problem?

Comment: @Ash let's say we have a web form project. User fills the form, then submits. Then admins recieve an e-mail for approving the changes on the user filled form. I want to develop this in a secure way, so asking for if it is appropriate to use a token or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSRF tokens are for validating the current form submission. Once a user clicked on the 'Reset password' button, then the token is validated and form will be accepted/rejected. IF you want to reopen the submitted form for admin, then re-opened form will use a new token for that form submission, so it is not useful to use old token to validate the request send to admin.

Instead you can generate some random key specific to each user request and can be store it into a database or file. later this key can be used for validating request.

Comment: that's the answer i wanted. So tokens cannot be used for user requests. I have to generate random key for each user request. Thank you.